# Computing the curvature of a surface through the area of a geodesic disk

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_formulas) has the following formula for the curvature of a surface:

$$K = \lim_{r\to 0}12 \frac{\pi r^2 - A(r)}{\pi r^4}$$
where $A(r)$ is the area of a geodesic disk.

Now, in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029001150), in Theorem $3.1$, page $337-338$, they have an approximation for the volume of a $n-ball$ of radius $r$. In the case $n=2$, their approximation:
$$V(r) = \pi r^2\bigg(1 - \frac{\tau(R)}{24}r^2 + O(r^4)\bigg)$$
where $R$ is the curvature tensor and $\tau(R) = \sum_i R_{ii}$ and $R_{ij} = \sum_k R_{ijik}$ as defined on page $333$ of the paper.

However, isn't $R_{ii}$ as defined always zero? In general, we have $R_{ijkl} + R_{jikl} = 0$ and therefore $2R_{iikl} = 0$ so that $R_{ii} = \tau(R) = 0$? This would seem to imply that $K = 0$ identically for any surface!

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $R_{ij} = \sum R_{ikjk}$ is the Ricci tensor here. You've got a typo up there or else they have one in the paper. (Of course, for a surface, Ricci curvature is just the scalar (Gaussian) curvature.)

Comment: Ok thanks, it looks like a typo in the paper.